# why does it execute properly only when the or conditions are between brackets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def is_devisable(n,m): #checks divisibility
    if n%m==0:
        return True
    return False




def is_devisable23n8(x): #checks if x is devisable by 2 or 3 and not 8
    if is_devisable(x,8)==False and is_devisable(x,3)==True or is_devisable(x,2)==True:
    return 'Yes'
return 'No'

is_devisable23n8(16)
>>>Yes
```

but if we add brackets to the `or` conditions:

```
#if the 2nd fn is with brackets:
def is_devisable23n8(x): #checks if x is devisable by 2 or 3 and not 8
    if is_devisable(x,8)==False and (is_devisable(x,3)==True or is_devisable(x,2)==True):
    return 'Yes'
return 'No'
is_devisable23n8(16)
>>> No
```

why is it executing properly only with brackets? It seems that Python is neglecting the first condition in the `if` statement (`is_devisable(x,8)==False`)? How does Python deals with `and` `if` statements having conditions including `or` and `and` on the same line?

Comment: It's called [Boolean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). Check it out.

Comment: `is_devisable(x,3)==True` equates to `True` if the method returns `True`. Really, just write `is_devisable(x,3)`

Comment: Note: `if is_devisable(x,8) == False` can be written `if not is_devisable(x,8)`

Comment: Thank you very much MattdMo, Andrew Sephard, and james bond)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Boolean arithmetic, `and` is analogous to multiplication and `or` to addition. Multiplication has precedence over addition, so `and` has precedence over `or`. This means that the `and` operation will be evaluated before the `or`... unless you put parentheses around `or` and force it to be evaluated first, as you have done. In other words, your first example is the same as:

```
if (is_divisible(x, 8) == False and is_divisible(x, 3) == True) or is_divisible(x, 2) == True:
```

In general, I like using more parentheses than I strictly need, so I don't have to remember which operator has precedence, and neither does the poor sap who eventually has to maintain my code (who is usually some future version of me).

By the way, you don't need the `== False` and `== True` part. You can just write:

```
if not is_divisible(x, 8) and (is_divisible(x, 3) or is_divisible(x, 2)):
```

In fact, that's kind of the whole point of naming a function something like `is_divisible`... `if is_divisible(...)` reads pretty nicely. I have taken the liberty of correcting the spelling of "divisible" for similar reasons.

Comment: I think you need a `not` on the `is_divisible(x,8)`

Comment: Yeah, I just copied and pasted that part of the code. Fixing...

Comment: kindall - I'm SOO thankful, i learned ALOT of things from your answer...